# Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox won't use the full screen

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a Windows 8 machine.  At first 14.04 was awesome, used up my entire screen, and I could use it as the main machine.  Then Ubuntu updated, and I lost my nice beautiful full screen.  Now it is back to acting like 12.04 or the 13's, and the wonderfulness that was Trusty Tahr has gone away, how can I get that back?  How can I roll-back the latest update so I could have my computer back?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to (and should not!) roll-back the last update. Just reinstall the Virtual Box Additions; it is necessary to do so after kernel upgrade, which is almost certainly your case. After re-installation of Virtual Box Additions, you will have proper full screen support back.